# How can I plot posterior predictive checks with a data.frame of data and an array of posterior samples?

Tags: r, arrays, plot, predictive

I am looking for a solution to plotting posterior predictive samples after developing an MCMC Gibbs sampler. Trouble is, I am unsure how to plot the observed data (a data.frame) over boxplots of my posterior samples (stored in an array) where the row entires in the data.frame correspond to the columns of the array. Unfortunately, it took me months  to develop an algorithm to get my posterior samples, so I am not interested in changing the arrangement of my posterior samples. I have provided a simplified example of how my data is set up below (in reality I have 200 obs.y and 10000 posterior samples for each obs.y so I cannot plot it by hand as I have below).

```
set.seed(11)

#example data#
obs.y=rnorm(5, 0, 10)
obs.x=rnorm(5, 1, 10)
dat=data.frame(obs.y, obs.x)

plot(obs.y,obs.x, main="data")

#example posterior samples for each obs.y (pretend I have implemented a MCMC algorithm to come up with these datapoints)#
post=array(NA, dim=c(100,5,1))
for (i in 1:100){
post[i,,] <- mvrnorm(1, obs, diag(15, 5, 5))}

#desired result#
boxplot(as.data.frame(post[,,]), ylim=c(-30,30))
points(1,dat$obs.y[1], col="green")
points(2,dat$obs.y[2], col="green")
points(3,dat$obs.y[3], col="green")
points(4,dat$obs.y[4], col="green")
points(5,dat$obs.y[5], col="green")
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: `points(1:5, dat$obs.y, col="green")`

Comment: lol that was  pretty simple. thank you. any tips for how to make the x axis dat$obs.x in addition? In other words, given the value for obs.x, i'd like a boxplot for post with the obs.y overlaid.